# can't make image gameObject invisible with (CanvasRenderer.cull) function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so with following code I am trying to make two images visibility gone. But the images that are added on canvas wont change visibility.

Here's simple code:

```
public GameObject g;
public GameObject ga;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    g.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>().cull = false;

    ga.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>().cull = false;


}
```

here g and ga is assigned from the editor. and the script is executing as its also attached to a gameobject.

And this is the before and after screenshot as the scene stays same:
[image]

[image]
update - I don't wanna make it inactive.
a bit more information - I want to place some UI elements behind those images so I want to make the images be invisible and also if possible keep the canvas object active. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get you. Your last question is marked as a duplicate and the duplicate shows ways to hide object (De-activate Object or disable the component). Why ask this question again?

Comment: so that answer showed two ways(SetActive and canvasRenderer), but this question is about those are not working and also not working in the described way, which is a simple way. Thanks.

Comment: *"but this question is about those are not working"* I assume you're new but it doesn't work like that. If the solution in your last question or the duplicate did not work for you, you edit your question and add the new code that doesn't work then explain what the new issue is. After that you can use @username to notify the person that left an answer or the person that closed the question that it's not working and they will reply to you based on your edit.

Comment: thanks for information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two Image under the Canvas named "Image" and "Image (1)" and you want to hide them or make them invisible without de-activating the Canvas.

You have two options:

**1**.De-activate the the "Image" and "Image (1)".

Find the two GameObjects holding both Images

```
GameObject imgObj1 = GameObject.Find("Image");
GameObject imgObj2 = GameObject.Find("Image (1)");
```

De-activate/Hide them

```
imgObj1.SetActive(false);
imgObj2.SetActive(false);
```

---

**2**.Disable the the component. The component that is dispalying that image under the Canvas is actually the [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) or [`RawImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) component.

Find the two GameObjects holding both Images

```
GameObject imgObj1 = GameObject.Find("Image");
GameObject imgObj2 = GameObject.Find("Image (1)");
```

Get the Image or RawImage Component from each one

```
Image img1 = imgObj1.GetComponent<Image>();
Image img2 = imgObj2.GetComponent<Image>();
```

Disable/Hide them

```
img1.enabled = false;
img2.enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

The API says

> Indicates whether geometry emitted by this renderer is ignored.

Shouldn't the bool be TRUE?

Could you not use

```
this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

to disable the gameobject and make it invisble?

Comment: thanks for the comment. I dont want to use SetActive(false). That works but I want to hide the canvas too and that has coroutine. So looking for other ways. And I dont know what to do with first lines of - geometry renderer off.

Comment: _I dont want to use SetActive(false)_. Some background information might help here.

Comment: Perhaps this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanvasRenderer.SetAlpha.html ?

Comment: And if you have to handle multiple UI elements to hide maybe put it into a canvas group? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html and then canvasgroup.alpha = 0

Comment: Thanks for the information and links and I'll update after I try those links.

Comment: Maybe you want to post your solution as an answer? This way it would benefit everyone.

Comment: Forget my last comment please. Haven't recognized there is an answer already.